# Generate iframe and communicate via post message issues

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, communication, postmessage

Here is my example code I am trying to get working. Although the iframe never writes the received message.

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.setAttribute('src', 'about:blank');
window.document.body.appendChild(frame);

var frameDoc = frame.contentWindow.document;
frameDoc.body.appendChild(frameDoc.createTextNode('Hi!'));

var code = 'window.addEventListener("message", function(){document.body.innerHTML = "Recieved Message"});';
var loaded = 'window.onload = function(){' + code + '};';
var val = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">' + loaded + '</scr' + 'ipt>';

frameDoc.open();
frameDoc.write(val);
frameDoc.close();

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('posting message...');
    window.postMessage({
    foo: 'bar'
  },'*');
}, 1000);
```

The goal I am trying to eventually reach is testing iframe communication in JSDOM, but I cannot even get this working in the browser yet.

Anyone have any ideas...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
> ```
>
> *otherWindow*
>
> **A reference to another window**; such a reference may be obtained, for
>   example, **using the contentWindow property of an iframe element**, the
>   object returned by window.open, or by named or numeric index on
>   window.frames.

You are using the `window` object of your page, when you need to be using the `window` object of the target, eg the iframe. Thus, you need to use `frame.contentWindow`

```
frame.contentWindow.postMessage({
    foo: 'bar'
},'*');
```

Comment: Ahh!! thank you. That makes sense now. Here is a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/6k7zpb8b/

Comment: Even better... I don't know why I thought I had to write script tags into the iframe.... https://jsfiddle.net/6k7zpb8b/1/